# Ionic popup confirm is not executing code in an if statement

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, popup

I have code behind a button that, once pressed, the button is meant to call a function to throw a pop up on screen. Either way if the user selects ok or dance, another function will be called. The problem is neither of these two functions are being called. Am I missing something very obvious?

```
$scope.user = {};
// A confirm dialog
$scope.showConfirm = function() {
var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
               title: 'T&Cs',
               template: 'Do you agree to the terms and conditions?'
               });
confirmPopup.then(function(res) {
               if( res ) {
                   signIn(user)
               } else {
                   logout();
               }
        });
  };
```

Comment: I assume that the 2 functions signIn and logout are not defined. Also I can't see if user is defined. I can see $scope.user, but not var user. What does console say? Where are they defined?

Comment: Hi Ant, both functions are defined and are working as they are meant to be outside of the if/else statement. User is also defined in another part of the code (it's a controller for an app so it's too big to throw up here). Nothing in the console to say there was an error. The pop up appears as expected but clicking ok/cancel results in nothing happening.

Comment: Can you demo this behaviour in codepen?

Comment: Ok, I have got it working. Everything was fine  bar the calling of the function in the if statement. Basically I was not setting the scope so while the function call read:     "signIn(user)"
It should read:
                                      "$scope.signIn($scope.user);"

All good now though. Thanks for the help. I will edit the above code to show the correct code

Comment: Yep though this was a scope issue. For any other viewers of this post please refer to http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp for an explanation of scope in JS.

Comment: Best to put the question back to how it was then in an answer explain the mistake so any future readers of this post can get an answer to help them.

Comment: Changed the answer back to the original as Ant suggested, cheers Ant. The fix is explained in comment 2

Answer (score 0):

When working in javascript you need to understand scope. This is best explained here... w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp.

In brief:

$scope is predefined in a controller (angular) and as such is available anywhere in that one controller. $rootScope is available in all controllers. Please see this example of scope:

```
.controller('ctrl1', function($scope, $rootScope) { 

    var a = 1;
    $scope.a = 2;
    $rootScope.a = 3;

    var funct1 = function () {

        var b = 4;
        $scope.b = 5;
        $rootScope.b = 6;

        console.log(a) // returns 1 as inherits scope 
        console.log($scope.a) // returns 2 as inherits $scope scope
        console.log($rootScope.a) // returns 3 as inherits $rootScope scope 

        console.log(b) // returns 4 as shares scope 
        console.log($scope.b) // returns 5 as inherits $scope scope
        console.log($rootScope.b) // returns 6 as inherits $rootScope scope 


    }

    funct1();

    console.log(a); // returns 1 as shares scope
    console.log($scope.a); // returns 2 as inherits $scope scope
    console.log($rootScope.a); // returns 3 as inherits $rootScope scope
    console.log(b); // returns undefined as b is defined out of scope.
    console.log($scope.b); // returns 5 as inherits $scope scope
    console.log($rootScope.b); // returns 6 as inherits $rootScope scope

})
```

Assuming the code in ctrl1 has already executed the only defined variables accessible from other controllers would be $rootScope.a and $rootScope.b. All others would be out of scope and as such undefined.

This is an oversimplification but serves to explain $scope and $rootScope in angular to beginners.

A common mistake is to confuse the definition of variables and objects `$scope` and `$rootScope` with `var x = y;` Check this first i.e. users vs $scope.users, if this is ok then look at scope as the next test.